# C# ASP.Net Core: display default controller and view in url

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.Net Core.

I have a small sample site running on my desktop (development).  I can launch the site in DEBUG mode and a browser comes up.  The initial URL displayed is just:

```
    https://localhost:12345/
```

I would like it to be:

```
    https://localhost:12345/Home/Index
```

or whatever the starting `controller` and `view` will be.  I can append the `controller` and `view` to the initial URL but is there a way to have them there by default?  I have done some goggling but I must not know the right terms to use.

Ideas?

**Edit**

my routes in `startup.cs` look like:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

It does not appear that .Net Core 2.1 offers a `url` option.

**Edit 2**

My goal is to literally have the "default" controller and view names appear in the browser's URL when I get to the "home" page.  As of this moment, when I launch the app in a browser in debug mode, all I see in the URL display is "https://localhost:12345/".  I have not tried to publish this so I do not know what a production version might do.

Comment: Is your intent that it start on that address just for debugging, or do you need it to start there in production as well?

Comment: I have not tried this in production yet but i assume that I would want it in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your request ,you could use a Rewriter middleware as follow:

```
var rules = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect(@"^.{0}$", "/Home/Index");
app.UseRewriter(rules);

app.UseMvc(
    routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "defaults",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want this, as the current behavior is actually better and more standard. However, the way to stop it is to remove the defaults from the route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

Then, the controller/action portions of the route will be required, and `HomeController.Index` can only be access by literally specifying the route `/Home/Index`. However, that's going to remove your root route, so going directly to  `https://localhost:12345`, without any path, will throw a 404.

Comment: Hi Chris, my goal is to literally see at least the controller and view in the browser's URL.  As you say, removing the defaults in the template throws a 404 when reaching for the home page.